# Symfony 5 + Doctrine - Add a Filter to every request, based on current user

Tags: php, symfony, events, filter, doctrine

I'm trying to dynamically set a "tenant_id" filter on some actions of my Controllers.

I've built a class which extends `SQLFilter` and put inside `addFilterConstraint` the logic to do that.

The problem is the dynamic "tenant" parameter:

If I put this piece of code inside each of my Controllers actions it works:

```php
$em->getFilters()->getFilter('tenant')->setParameter('tenant_id', $security->getUser()->getTenant()->getId());
```

Of course this is not maintainable so I'm trying to move this logic somewhere else to make it cleaner and easier to maintain.

I'm thinking to something like an Event, but I would need to dispatch an `Event` on every `Request`, when the `Security` has already done it's job and then I'd need to modify the `EntityManager`.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for an event subscriber: https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber this can be ran on every `onKernelRequest` for example..

Comment: I've found this too, but I don't know how to access EntityManager and Security since these classes only receives the Event, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an event subscriber ([Ref](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber))

Here is an example you can use showing access to the entity manager and security classes. place this file in `src/EventSubscriber/TenantFilterEventSubscriber.php` this will then run on every request.

```
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class TenantFilterEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        if (!is_array($controller)) return;

        if ($controller[0] instanceof YourController) {
            $user = $this->security->getUser();

            if (null !== $user) {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'kernel.controller' => 'onKernelController',
        );
    }
}
```